# Android webview, loading css live file, add local

Tags: android, css, webview

Am using android webview tutorial based create application. how to get local file in live android.  Coding given below help me.

```
String htmlData;
htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"Style.css\" />";
//lets assume we have /assets/style.css file
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");`
implement css file in html file. So add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />` in html head section.